# spoj dp lsort approach

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

http://www.spoj.com/problems/LSORT/ It is a problem on spoj
It states that

You are given a permutation of n numbers that are between 1 to n and having no duplicates.
Task is to sort that permutation in ascending order.There is another array Q in which we are inserting elements from given permutation P.

You have to implement N steps to sort P. In the i-th step, P has N-i+1 remaining elements, Q has i-1 elements and you have to choose some x-th element (from the N-i+1 available elements) of P and put it to the left or to the right of Q. The cost of this step is equal to x * i. The total cost is the sum of costs of individual steps. After N steps, Q must be an ascending sequence. Your task is to minimize the total cost.

Input

The first line of the input file is T (T ≤ 10), the number of test cases. Then descriptions of T test cases follow. The description of each test case consists of two lines. The first line contains a single integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000). The second line contains N distinct integers from the set {1, 2, .., N}, the N-element permutation P.

Output

For each test case your program should write one line, containing a single integer - the minimum total cost of sorting.

Now i have figured out the dp
My recurrence relation states that for getting most optimal values from elements having value i to j i will have to insert either $i$ at front or $j$ at back.

Cost of inserting **i** at front = **dp[i+1][j]**+**cost of adding element i at front**

Cost of inserting **j** at back = **dp[i][j-1]** +**cost of adding element j at back**

and i have to take minimum of these.answer would be dp[1][n]

```
for(l=1;l<=n;l++) //length of current permutation Q
{
  for(i=1;i<=n-l+1;i++) //starting value of permutation Q
  {
   j=i+l-1;  //ending value of permutation Q
   dp[i][j]=min(dp[i+1][j]+l*xi,dp[i][j-1]+l*xj);//chosing wether to insert i at start or j at end
  }
}
```

here xi=index of element **i** from start of permutation P.

and yi=index of element **j** from start of permutation P.

ans would be dp[1][n]

But am unable to figure out xi and xj
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try re-thinking your DP state.

For me, I would use the dp[startQ][endQ] where dp[startQ][endQ] means the cost I have incurred to far to 'sort' values startQ to endQ in the array Q.

If you know what is in the array Q (integers startQ to endQ inclusive), one can easily re-construct the  array of P by just removing/ignoring all the integers within startQ and endQ.

For each state, dp[startQ][endQ], since one can only add to the front or the back of Q, 
dp[startQ][endQ] can only be:

dp[startQ][endQ-1] + cost of adding endQ
dp[startQ-1][endQ] + cost of adding startQ

with the base cases being
dp[i][i] = 0;

These states can be computed and the answer can be found at dp[1]][n]; (assuming it is one indexed).
However I haven't thought of a efficient way to compute `x` if it were to be coded in a top down manner, where as the whole computation can be performed in O(N^2 log N) using bottom-up DP with a data structure to compute `x` at every state.

I will leave the final details for you to code out :) but I can help more if required.